# Can I ask the same question twice?

Tags: support, answers, asking-questions, unanswered-questions

I asked a question but since it was very long, nobody answered me. I'm wondering if I should ask it again as a new question again (Of course I will make it much simpler than before) or should I just edit it?

Comment: "Can you" yes.  "Should you" no.

Comment: Related: [Legitimate methods for attracting attention to an old unansweed question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10251/legitimate-methods-for-attracting-attention-to-an-old-unansweed-question) and [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/how-to-grab-users-attention-on-an-old-question)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just edit it.

**Don't**, no matter what else you do, ask the exact same question twice. It will be closed as a duplicate, and people will think it is impolite.

If you don't get an answer to your question, you can **edit** it (preferably with additional information and clarifications), which will have the effect of bumping the question up the active list. If you still don't get an answer, [try out the bounty system](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: "With additional information and clarifications"  Normally we would ask for this.  But the OP says his question was "very long" so maybe that was the problem.  In that case, making it shorter and clearer could be the goal.

Comment: @GEdgar: "additional clarifications" can come in the form of removing cruft.